# IndexError: list index out of range I don't understand

Tags: python, list, indexing

This program is supposed to take all numbers that are divisible by 3 and 5 and add them all together, but I dont understand, I try to run this script and it just keeps giving me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "first.py", line 23, in <module>
main()
File "first.py", line 19, in main
merica = merica + good[count-1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I dont understand what this means, because

```
count-1
```

is in the range of the indexes it seems right?

```
def main():
    merica = 0
    commonfactors = []
    good = []
    count = 1

    while count <= 1000:
            if count%3 == 0:
                    good.append(count)
            elif count%5 == 0:
                    if count in good:
                            commonfactors.append(count)
                    else:
                            good.append(count)
            count = count+1
    count = count - 1000
    while count <= 1000:
            merica = merica + good[count-1]
            count = count+1
    print(merica)
main()
exit()
```

Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: Have you printed `count-1` at the place you get the error?

Comment: And the `len(good)`?  There's an assumption there you're making.

Answer (score 0):

This entire block is assuming some length of `good` that isn't accurate.

```
while count <= 1000:
        merica = merica + good[count-1]
        count = count+1
```

If you're only putting a *subset* of your numbers in there, the length can't be 1000.

Regardless, you should learn about the built in `sum()` function:

```
good = [1, 2, 3]
merica = sum(good)
```

You might also find the `range()` function helpful as well:

```
for number in range(1000):
    # This will loop 1000 times with number equal to 0 to 999.
```

This is turning into a code review ... but why are you doing this:

```
count = count - 1000
```

Instead of just setting `count = 0`?

You could also benefit from some more defensive style programming.  Learn how to use `assert`:

```
count = count - 1000
assert count == 0
```

and

```
assert count-1 < len(good)
merica = merica + good[count-1]
```

These assertions will help you quickly track down assumptions you are making.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you only append number to good when the count is multiple of 3 or 5 (not both).

So, the size of good won't be 1000.

That's why you are getting error.

your below loop will run only upto count <=466.

```
def main():
    merica = 0
    commonfactors = []
    good = []
    count = 1

    while count <= 1000:
            if count%3 == 0:
                    good.append(count)
            elif count%5 == 0:
                    if count in good:
                            commonfactors.append(count)
                    else:
                            good.append(count)
            count = count+1
    count = count - 1000
    while count <= len(good):
            merica = merica + good[count-1]
            count = count+1
    print(merica)
main()
exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the error says the list index is out of range, let's consider how long the list is and what index we try to use. In here, theres the assumption that the list `good` has 1000 items in it because the while loop goes up to 1000.

```
while count <= 1000:
        merica = merica + good[count-1]
        count = count+1
```

Okay, so now we see the program expects the list to have 1000 items in it. Let's see if this holds true when we construct the list.

```
while count <= 1000:
        if count%3 == 0:
                good.append(count)
        elif count%5 == 0:
                if count in good:
                        commonfactors.append(count)
                else:
                        good.append(count)
        count = count+1
```

Now we see the list is being constructed by appending values to it where the values go from 1 to 1000. But we apply a condition to append it, that is, it has to be either divisible by 3 or 5. So what about prime numbers? There's no `else` block appending these numbers. Thus we don't append the full set of 1000 numbers but only append those divisible by 5 or 3.

The solution is change our assumption about the size of the loop in the second while block. `while count <= len(good):` will adjust the length based on the size of the list.